# Is there any way to call a desktop application that is installed on a server from a web site?

Tags: c#, user-interface, asp.net-core, server, client

I have a site written in ASP.NET Core and used ASP boilerplate. Also, I'll have a desktop application which will be installed at the same server. I need to know if it's possible to run this app from my site using it's GUI. Because after running it, I need to save some data from this app. I tried on my local `System.Diagnostics.Process` and it calls the GUI but I don't know if it is possible in the server.